# Should I use index() in relationships?

Tags: laravel

I'm not sure when to use index() in migration.

I'll give an example:

- User Table
- User Bank Detail Table

Currently, I have written it like:

```
Schema::create('bankdetails', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    ...
});
```

And I'm fetching the relationship with

```
public function bankdetail(){
    return $this->hasOne(Bankdetail::class);
}
```

Would you still use index() in this case?

And what confuses me, is Jeff's GitHub [project](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/council/blob/master/database/migrations/2017_03_14_180530_create_replies_table.php), you will see that he rarely uses index().

Besides that, if I'm setting a foreign key to it

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

do I still need to use Index()?

Comment: It's not a requirement, but an optimization. If you query on tables using something other than the primary_key (which is already inherently indexed), then it would perform better. An example of when to use this is when you have bankdetails.id, but have a query to get bankdetails by account number (instead of id). Indexing an account number would return faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index()` adds indexes to your database. To know when to use `index()` in a migration, you need to understand when to add an index to your database.

An index is a copy of selected columns of data from a table that can be searched very efficiently. A database index allows a query to efficiently retrieve data from a database. Indexes are related to specific tables and consist of one or more columns.

Rightly implementing indexes boosts query performance, but also adds extra costs of additional writes and storage space to maintain the index data structure. You must be sure to use indexes judiciously.

**Considerations in selecting an index**

1. Index the most heavily used queries. In other words, select indexes by workload, not by table.
2. Maintain a balance on number of indexes, since they introduce extra costs to maintain them. But don't place a cap on total number of indexes.
3. Index columns for important or prioritised queries.
4. Index columns that are sorted or grouped, to increase performance.
5. Index columns that hold unique data (like email or username)
6. Index columns that hold foreign keys
7. Index columns that will increase chances for index-only access. If a query on an indexed column returns data from a few other columns, you can index those columns to improve performance of that query.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "should i use `index()` on `user_id` or `id`" then the answer is no.

one is a primary key cause of the `increments()` method wich is inherently indexed.
and the other is a foreign key wich is inherently indexed too.

When to use it:
when you have a field (preferably an integer one) used in the `where` conditions in your queries.

Example: if you have `status` field containing values (0,1,2,3...) you should `index()` it.

Comment: I don't think that a foreign key is inherently indexed, are you sure about that?

Comment: @exSnake depends on the database, but it is true for MySQL "MySQL requires that foreign key columns be indexed; if you create a table with a foreign key constraint but no index on a given column, an index is created." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-foreign-key.html#:~:text=MySQL%20requires%20that%20foreign%20key,column%2C%20an%20index%20is%20created.&text=Information%20about%20foreign%20keys%20on,tables%2C%20in%20the%20INFORMATION_SCHEMA%20database.